# Google cloud SDK - OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Hash._SHA256' on mac

Tags: macos, google-cloud-sdk

On Mac I followed the instructions on https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-macos to install Google cloud SDK

But when I ran `google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`:
I got:

```
OSError: Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Hash._SHA256'
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix it I had the change the default python version that I had updated in `.bash_profile`.
I removed this line:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
```

It switched back to Python 2.7.10 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

2022 solution for [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk) installer

Use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/index_it)

`enter code here`brew install python@3.7

Then open a new Terminal shell and run installer again:

```
$HOME/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

When asked to install Python 3.7 modules accept it:

```
Download and run Python 3.7 installer? (Y/n)?  

Running Python 3.7 installer, you may be prompted for sudo password...
Password:
installer: Package name is Python
installer: Installing at base path /
installer: The install was successful.
Setting up virtual environment
Creating virtualenv...
Installing modules...
     |████████████████████████████████| 89 kB 3.6 MB/s 
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.2 MB 734 kB/s 
     |████████████████████████████████| 2.6 MB 2.5 MB/s 
     |████████████████████████████████| 149 kB 6.5 MB/s 
     |████████████████████████████████| 178 kB 5.7 MB/s 
     |████████████████████████████████| 118 kB 4.5 MB/s 
  Building wheel for crcmod (setup.py) ... done
Virtual env enabled.
```

Then you can start using `gcloud`, `gsutil` commands.